# Exception Handling Adventure III - Updated

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I have this following java code skeleton -

```
        try {
            Question q = null; //List of questions. I have put 3 in the list, in my main function
            int i = 0;
            while (i <= questions.size()) {
                System.out.println("iteration " + i);
                q = questions.get(i);
                try {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Script completed"); 
                        break;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // script is still executing... continue
                    }
                    //My entire logic is here.An exception is thrown in the first iteration
                    i++;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //The thrown exception is caught here
                    try {
                    //The caught exception is handled here
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    System.out.println("IO Exception..");
                }
            }
        }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("No more communication due to the lack of data");
        } catch (IllegalMonitorStateException imse) {
            System.out.println("Illegal Monitor State Exception");
        } catch (IllegalThreadStateException itse) {
            System.out.println("Illegal Thread State Exception");
        }
```

---

And the **output** i get is somewhat like this -

```
iteration 0
//Exception handling related output

iteration 0  //repeated because i++ doesn't happen since exception is thrown
//Execution takes place normally

iteration 1
//????????  -  Here is where i am facing the problem. I am not getting
```

the output completely.I know the reason why i am still in iteration 1 (it has got to do with i++, which doesn't happen once due to the exception thrown for the first time). But can anybody help me how to successfully execute this iteration also?

Comment: There's definitely not enough information here

Comment: Providing an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) not only helps us give a better answer, but the process of building it might help you find the answer yourself. Try to do that in the future!

Comment: Why in the world do you need to catch Exception in this many places? Nested try blocks like this is a gigantic code smell

Comment: @matt : Because in each and every try block, there are several conditions to be taken care of. And you are right. This is quite a huge code.So i tried to make it as simple as possible.

Comment: @adam: i considered your comment and i have made my attempt to improvise my code skeleton. Please do let me know if some information is missing.

Comment: Note that having `catch (IllegalMonitorStateException)` or `catch (IllegalThreadStateException)` is a **definite** code-smell, as those two exceptions can **always** be avoided by writing correct code (even more so than `NullPointerException`.

Comment: i removed the catch blocks u mentioned...but still doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check **which** `catch` block gets executed in each iteration. If an exception is thrown in `//try3` or `//try4` (or if no exception is thrown at all), then `i++` **will be** executed.

If an exception is thrown in `//try2` (either *before* `//try3` or *after* `//catch4`), then `i++` **will not be** executed.

Comment: I know what is hapening. But I am trying to figure out how t overcome that. Unfortunately, I've not been successful